# Time complexity of a randomized algorithm for finding a frequently-occurring element?

Tags: performance, algorithm, random, big-o, time-complexity

I always have trouble analysing the running time of randomized algorithms. I would be grateful if someone could explain this to me.

Take for example the following code that I have written;

It checks for the element in an array that occur at least n/4 times. (n is the size of the array). It picks a random number from the array, checks if it occurs n/4 number of times. If it does, it returns it. Else it deletes all occurrences of the element and continues.

Assume that there is at least one such element in the array which occurs at least n/4 number of times.

```
elements_left = n ;

    frequency ( A[] )
      {
        k -> pick a random element from A[] ;
        int count = 0;
        int delete_count = 0;

        for (i=0 ; i < elements_left ; i++)
          {  
            if (a[i] = k)
                count++ ;
          }

        if (count >= n/4)
            return A[i] ;
            exit ;

        else
          {
            for (i=0 ; i < elements_left ; i++)
              {  
                if (A[i] = k)
                    delete (A[i]) ;
                    delete_count ++ ;
              }

            elements_left = n - delete_count ;
          }

        frequency (A[])
      }
```

What would the Worst case running time and Expected running time of this algorithm be and how would you derive it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[templatetypedef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19673825/56778) describes the case when there is an element that occurs n/4 times.

The worst case run time is O(n^2), which will happen if all of the items are unique.

The average case is very difficult to determine. Say the array contains 100 items. All are unique except one, which occurs 15 times. So you will have to make at least 40 recursive calls to remove enough items for that individual item to be returned as a result. But at the first iteration there's a 15/100 chance that you will remove that most frequent item. The next time there's a 15/99 chance, etc. It's highly likely (almost a certainty) that by the time you made 40 selections, you'd pick that most frequent item and delete it from the array.

So, if you know that there is an element that occurs n/4 times, the expected runtime is O(n). Otherwise the runtime is highly dependent on the distribution of items, with a worst case running time of O(n^2).

Comment: That is so helpful. Could you explain how the complexity would change if I DON'T delete the elements from the array? Instead, I just check if the random element occurs n/4 times, if it doesn't proceed with picking the next random element.

Comment: If you don't delete elements after an unsuccessful selection, then the the algorithm will never terminate in the case where there is no element that occurs n/4 times. If there is an element that occurs at least n/4 times, then the algorithm remains O(n).

Answer (score 3):

One way to think about this is the following: on each iteration of the algorithm, you will do O(n) work to check whether the element you randomly chose is the one you want. If so, you're done. If not, you do some amount of work to remove all other copies of that element from the array. Your pseudocode above doesn't really specify how you're removing them (I don't know that it means to delete an individual array element), but I'll assume that the runtime is O(n), since it's possible to remove all copies of an element in that time.

The question now is how many rounds, on expectation, are necessary to find the element? Since the element has probability 1/4 of getting chosen, on expectation it will take 4 tries to find it. Each try does Θ(n) work - there will always be between n/4 and n total elements - and so the runtime will be Θ(n) on expectation (four iterations of Θ(n) work.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you explain the line 'Each try does Θ(n) work - there will always be between n/4 and n total elements' ? And what do you mean by On Expectation?

Comment: @AbhijitBadjatya- the term "on expectation" is synonymous with "on average." When you're talking about an average case analysis, you're looking at the expected value of the runtime. Also, if there is some array element that appears n/4 times or more, the algorithm will never reduce the size of the array below n/4 when deleting elements it picked incorrectly, so the array size is always between n (at the start) and n/4 (in the worst case if all picks are bad.)